# Windows 10 symbolic links: Finer grained than developer mode?

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, user-permissions, symbolic-link

We have a number of external developers who are not administrators on their Windows 10 machines. In a new project, we have a git repository with lots of symbolic links which we would like to actually deploy as symbolic links in the file system.

I'm trying to convince management to grant the right to create symbolic links. That would be easier if they did not need full developer mode which grants additional rights which are not needed.

From what I read, creating symbolic links by regular users requires two conditions to be true:

- The [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/create-symbolic-links) is enabled
- Developer mode is enabled.

My question is basically whether the rights granted by activating developer mode can instead be granted selectively, without e.g. the right to "sideload" applications. (Perhaps that is exactly what the group policy in the first bullet point does, but it is not clear to me.)

Granting fewer rights would make it easier to convince management.

Comment: Why not "deploy" using the usual and customary account for one off elevated activities, and use a normal account the remaining 99.99% of the time? I doubt there is a lot of prescriptive guidance for a management audience here for when developer mode is enabled. Really narrow use case. Also worth mentioning that "Sideload apps is a more secure option than Developer Mode" per Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/developer-mode-features-and-debugging

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/200627/93133